# listbox not working in C#

Tags: listbox

I would like to add items to list box.
It's completely fine in the button click function.
However, if I put it in other function, it doesn't work.

or in other words, I can see "start" in the box, but not the "mission".

Thanks

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("start");
        listBox1.Items.Add("start");
        token = textBox1.Text;
        shipid = textBox2.Text;
        host = textBox3.Text;
        shipid = shipid.Replace(",", "%2C");
        System.Timers.Timer t = new System.Timers.Timer(5000);
        t.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(Mission3);
        t.AutoReset = true;
        t.Enabled = true;
    }
    private void Mission3(object source, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        progress = action(progress, 0, 0, "0");
        listBox1.Items.Add("mission");
    }
```

Comment: quite a few things wrong with that....

Comment: sorry, I'm really new to C# and I don't have pretty much programming experience. Could you tell me how to make it works?